# 「Onsen UI最小限のテンプレート」で「Onsen UI Guide」にある「アラートダイアログを使う」を行うには

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

「Onsen UI最小限のテンプレート」で「Onsen UI Guide」にある「アラートダイアログを使う」を行いたいのですが、「アラートダイアログを使う」のHTMLとJSのソースコードをどのように「Onsen UI最小限のテンプレート」に適用すればアラートダイアログを出力できるのでしょうか。

index.htmlの

```
<script>
  ons.bootstrap();
</script>
```

を

```
<script>
    ons.bootstrap();

    .controller('NotificationController', function($scope) {
      $scope.alert = function() {
        ons.notification.alert({message: 'An error has occurred!'});
      }

      $scope.confirm = function() {
        ons.notification.confirm({
          message: 'Are you sure you want to continue?',
          callback: function(idx) {
            switch(idx) {
              case 0:
                ons.notification.alert({
                  message: 'You pressed "Cancel".'
                });
                break;
              case 1:
                ons.notification.alert({
                  message: 'You pressed "OK".'
                });
                break;
            }
          }
        });
      }

      $scope.prompt = function() {
        ons.notification.prompt({
          message: "Please enter your age",
          callback: function(age) {
            ons.notification.alert({
              message: 'You are ' + parseInt(age || 0) + ' years old.'
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });

</script>
```

にするとプレビュー画面は真っ白になります

これを無くして page1.html の

```
</ons-page>
```

の直前に

```
<ons-list ng-controller="NotificationController">
  <ons-list-item ng-click="alert()" modifier="tappable">
    Alert
  </ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item ng-click="confirm()" modifier="tappable">
    Confirm
  </ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item ng-click="prompt()" modifier="tappable">
    Prompt
  </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```

を加えただけだと、画面上に"Alert Confirm Prompt"という文字が表示されます。

本当に初歩的なことと思いますが、どうかご回答をお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

こんな感じでいけると思います。

index.html

```
<script>
    ons.bootstrap()
    .controller('NotificationController', function($scope) {
      $scope.alert = function() {
        ons.notification.alert({message: 'An error has occurred!'});
      }

      $scope.confirm = function() {
        ons.notification.confirm({
          message: 'Are you sure you want to continue?',
          callback: function(idx) {
            switch(idx) {
              case 0:
                ons.notification.alert({
                  message: 'You pressed "Cancel".'
                });
                break;
              case 1:
                ons.notification.alert({
                  message: 'You pressed "OK".'
                });
                break;
            }
          }
        });
      }

      $scope.prompt = function() {
        ons.notification.prompt({
          message: "Please enter your age",
          callback: function(age) {
            ons.notification.alert({
              message: 'You are ' + parseInt(age || 0) + ' years old.'
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
</script>
```

page1.html

```
<ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="center">Navigator</div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <ons-list ng-controller="NotificationController">
        <ons-list-item ng-click="alert()" modifier="tappable">
          Alert
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item ng-click="confirm()" modifier="tappable">
          Confirm
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item ng-click="prompt()" modifier="tappable">
          Prompt
        </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
</ons-page>
```

質問に書いてあるコードの`ons.bootstrap();`のセミコロンは不要です。

Comment: ita_3yさん
ありがとうございました。動作を確認することができました。